# Sprites not appearing correctly onscreen - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm in a game programming class and I'm supposed to make a game where there are sprites falling down from the top of the screen that you catch or avoid. Right now I'm working on making the objects fall and they were working at first but then I screwed something up because now they appear patchily/randomly disappear while falling down the screen. I've tried changing various things in the code to fix the problem but I've been stuck for a while.

I'm pretty certain that I messed something up either blitting the coal/candy to the screen or adding new ones to fall once others disappear, but I included a large portion of my code just in case something there is messing it up. I'll highlight the likely messed up sections below.

Oh, I also always really appreciate comments on how to make code more concise/efficient, but the teacher expects the code to be similar to how he taught us, so if you do have a specific fix, if it could keep the code similar to how it is right now I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you so much!

```
#Setting up time/timer
time = 6000
TICKTOCK = 0 
pygame.time.set_timer (TICKTOCK+1, 10)

#Class for candy
class Candy: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 150)
        self.y = random.randint(-1000, 0)
        self.image_Candy = pygame.image.load('konpeito.png')
        self.height = self.image_Candy.get_height()
        self.width = self.image_Candy.get_width()

    def collide (self, sprite):
        selfRect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        spriteRect = pygame.Rect(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.width, sprite.height)
        if selfRect.colliderect(spriteRect):
            return True
        else: 
            return False

#class for coal
class Coal: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 150)
        self.y = random.randint(-1000, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        self.image_Coal = pygame.image.load('coal.png') 
        self.width = self.image_Coal.get_width()
        self.height = self.image_Coal.get_height()

    def collide (self, sprite):
        selfRect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        spriteRect = pygame.Rect(sprite.x, sprite.y, sprite.width, sprite.height)
        if selfRect.colliderect(spriteRect):
            return True
        else: 
            return False

#class for sootsprite (collects candy and coal)
class Sootsprite:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
        self.y = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
        self.image_bowl = pygame.image.load('sootsprite.png')
        self.height = self.image_bowl.get_height()
        self.width = self.image_bowl.get_width()

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
fps = 10

#Creating candies and rocks
bowl = []
for i in range (15):
    candyInstance = Candy()
    bowl.append(candyInstance)

rocks = []
for i in range (8):
    coalInstance = Coal()
    rocks.append(coalInstance)

catch = Sootsprite()   

playground.fill(cyan)

Game_Over = False

while not Game_Over: 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
    endfont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    text = font.render('Points: ' + str(total) + '/15', True, black)
    playground.blit(text, (0,0))
    timer = font.render('Time remaining: ' + str(time), True, black)
    playground.blit(timer, (0, 40))
    end = endfont.render("GAME OVER." + str(total) + " POINTS EARNED", True, black)
```

This is where I blitted things onscreen and potentially screwed up:

```
    playground.blit(catch.image_bowl, (catch.x, catch.y))
    playground.blit(candyInstance.image_Candy, (candyInstance.x, candyInstance.y))
    playground.blit(coalInstance.image_Coal, (coalInstance.x, coalInstance.y))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Game_Over = True
        if event.type == TICKTOCK+1:
            time -=1
        #ends game when time is over
        if time < 0:
            playground.blit(end, (300, 400))

        #moving sootsprite with mouse
        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            (catch.x, catch.y) = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 

    #making candy fall    
    for candyInstance in bowl:
        if candyInstance.x <= 0: 
            candyInstance.x += 0 
        elif candyInstance.x >= 0 :
            candyInstance.x -=0 

        if candyInstance.y <= (SCREEN_HEIGHT+150): 
            candyInstance.y += 20  
        elif candyInstance.y > (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 150) :
            candyInstance.y = -100
```

this is where I'm removing things and adding new ones and might've messed up:

```
    #removing candy when collected        
    for candyInstance in bowl:
        if candyInstance.collide(catch):
            bowl.remove(candyInstance)
            total += 1
            candyInstance = Candy()
            bowl.append(candyInstance)

    #making coal fall
    for coalInstance in rocks:
        if coalInstance.x <= 0: 
            coalInstance.x += 0 
        elif coalInstance.x >= 0 :
            coalInstance.x -=0 

        if coalInstance.y <= (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200): 
            coalInstance.y += 20  
        elif coalInstance.y > (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200) :
            coalInstance.y = -100
```

this is also a place where I removed objects and added new ones:

```
    #removing coal when collected
    for coalInstance in rocks:
        if coalInstance.collide(catch):
            rocks.remove(coalInstance)
            total -= 1
            coalInstance = Coal()
            rocks.append(coalInstance)

    pygame.display.flip()
    playground.fill(cyan)
    clock.tick (fps) 

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: you have `bowl` list with 15 elements but you don't use it when you blit.

Comment: I've tried ways to blit with the lists, but I get errors such as "argument must be Surface, not list" or "list has no attribute 'image_xyz,'" is there a way I could incorporate a list into the blit statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `blit` only one candy. Use `for` loop to `blit` all candies.

```
for candyInstance in bowl:
    playground.blit(candyInstance.image_Candy, (candyInstance.x, candyInstance.y))
```

You have the same problem with `rocks`

```
for coalInstance in rocks:
    playground.blit(coalInstance.image_Coal, (coalInstance.x, coalInstance.y))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answers are always really helpful, I appreciate that you took the time to look over my code!

Comment: see example as suggestion how to organize code: http://pastebin.com/p2KAfsHH . Use `self.rect` to keep postion and size  (instead of `self.x`, `self,y`, `self.width`, `self. height`) and you can create `def draw(self, surface): surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)` in classes, and use it `candyInstance.draw(playground)`